# How to validate DatePickerDialog ?

Tags: android, datepicker

I create AgeCalculator.
I want to validate DatePickerDialog.. 
In my App when app is load system date will display
after that when I set birthdate from DatePicker, Date is set to TextView.

**BUT USER CAN NOT SET BIRTHDATE BIGGER THAN CURRENT DATE...**
here is my code

AgeCalculator.java

```
package com.example.agecalculator;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AgeCalculator extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    TextView currentDate, birthDate, ageDisplay;
    AgeCalculation age = null;
    static final int DATE_START_DIALOG_ID = 0;
    private int startYear = 2015;
    private int startMonth = 0;
    private int startDay = 8;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        age = new AgeCalculation();
        currentDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSysDate);
        currentDate.setText(age.getCurrentDate());
        birthDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtBirthDate);
        birthDate.setOnClickListener(this);
        ageDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAge);
        Calendar valid = Calendar.getInstance();
        int validYear = valid.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int validMonth = valid.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int validDay = valid.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_START_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, startYear,
                    startMonth, startDay);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
            startYear = selectedYear;
            startMonth = selectedMonth;
            startDay = selectedDay;
            age.setDateOfBirth(startYear, startMonth, startDay);
            birthDate.setText(selectedDay + "-" + (startMonth + 1) + "-"
                    + startYear);
            calculateAge();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.txtBirthDate:
            showDialog(DATE_START_DIALOG_ID);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    private void calculateAge() {
        age.calcualteYear();
        age.calcualteMonth();
        age.calcualteDay();

        ageDisplay.setText(age.getResult());
    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

AgeCalculation.java

```
package com.example.agecalculator;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class AgeCalculation {
    private Calendar end;
    private Calendar start;
    private int endYear;
    private int endMonth;
    private int endDay;
    private int startYear;
    private int startMonth;
    private int startDay;
    private int calYear;
    private int calMonth;
    private int calDay;

    public String getCurrentDate() {
        end = Calendar.getInstance();
        endYear = end.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        endMonth = end.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        endMonth++;
        endDay = end.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return endDay + "-" + endMonth + "-" + endYear;

    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(int sYear, int sMonth, int sDay) {
        startYear = sYear;
        startMonth = sMonth;
        startMonth++;
        startDay = sDay;

        if (sYear > endYear) {

        }

    }

    public void calcualteYear() {
        calYear = endYear - startYear;

    }

    public void calcualteMonth() {
        if (endMonth >= startMonth) {
            calMonth = endMonth - startMonth;
        } else {
            calMonth = endMonth - startMonth;
            calMonth = 12 + calMonth;
            calYear--;
        }

    }

    public void calcualteDay() {

        if (endDay >= startDay) {
            calDay = endDay - startDay;
        } else {
            calDay = endDay - startDay;
            calDay = 30 + calDay;
            if (calMonth == 0) {
                calMonth = 11;
                calYear--;
            } else {
                calMonth--;
            }

        }
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return "Day: " + calDay + "\n" + "Month:" + calMonth + "\n" + "Year:"
                + calYear;
    }

    public long getSeconde() {
        start = Calendar.getInstance();
        start.set(Calendar.YEAR, startYear);
        start.set(Calendar.MONTH, startMonth);
        start.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, startDay);
        start.set(Calendar.HOUR, 12);
        start.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        start.set(Calendar.SECOND, 60);
        start.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 60);
        long now = end.getTimeInMillis();
        long old = start.getTimeInMillis();
        long diff = old - now;
        return diff / 1000;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set max date in `DatePicker`.

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_START_DIALOG_ID:
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener,
                startYear, startMonth, startDay);
        // maxDateLong can be System.currentTimeMillis()
        dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxDateLong);
        return dialog;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: and what I write in maxDateLong // Function argument..

Comment: I wrote it as comment in code. It can be `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Comment: You can also use `Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()`.

Comment: Thanks a lote... that is exactly what I m looking for... :)